# Do transvaginal ultrasounds break the hymen if one is a virgin? Is it painful for a virgin?

Tags: pcos, transvaginal-ultrasound, ovarian-cysts, hymen

I was diagnosed with PCOS a number of years ago. Recently, my OBGYN set up an ultrasound for me to check on the status of my ovarian-cysts. I just thought it would be a normal pelvic ultrasound performed on the external part of my body, but I found out it will be an internal procedure known as "transvaginal ultrasound." From what I understand, that means the ultrasound wand is inserted into my vagina to take the imaging needed.

I am pretty nervous (honestly, scared out of my mind) because I'm a virgin. **Will a transvaginal ultrasound break my hymen as I am a virgin???** How much pain should I anticipate?

Comment: [This website page](http://www.doctorslounge.com/gynecology/forums/backup/topic-14728.html) may help with your question.  Plus I have seen [here](https://www.thh.nhs.uk/documents/_patients/patientleaflets/radiology/piid157-tv_ultrasound_scan-apr13.pdf) that they won't perform the scan on a virgin if they are informed of this.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you are interested in the hymen? Medically it is not that interesting (some women don't have hymen, in others it "breaks" when they use a tampon. besides, most doctors don't medically care about the cultural aspect of virginity), but culturally it can be. I would recommend you to ask your gynaecologist what the hymen is, and how the ultrasound might affect the hymen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During Transvaginal Ultrasaund procedure defloration (breaking a hymen) can happen but not necessarily;It depends on several factors.

Transvaginal Ultrasaund in virgins should be performed only with patent's signed informed consent form (or by close relatives if patient is not of legal age or is unable to do so).

This is very important,especially in culturally sensitive regions as can be detrimental for patient's future life,thus if defloration happens It will be documented and can be shown to the interested sides.

Informed consent is legal document that is intended to protect both:the patient and the doctor who performs the procedure.

Information mentioned above is derived from own practice.

Unfortunately no research or case report is available by online search.

Here is the forum link where you can find some answers:
http://www.doctorslounge.com/gynecology/forums/backup/topic-14728.html

Here is the popular article from news: 
http://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/3907422

Comment: It really depends on the culture you're in if written informed consent is required. I have never seen it happen in the Netherlands (where a lot fewer claims against health providers are made). Still, of course, consent is needed, but this can be spoken or implied.